# Unexpected results from bitwise logic operation

Tags: operators, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Given an enumeration defined like so:

```
enum DebugModeType {
    DebugModeNone = 0,
    DebugModeButton = 1,
    DebugModeFPS = 2,
    DebugModeData = 4
};
#define DebugMode DebugModeButton|DebugModeData
```

I expect the value of `DebugMode&DebugModeFPS` to be 0, but I observe it to be 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parentheses in your macro to overcome operator precedence:

```
#define DebugMode (DebugModeButton|DebugModeData)
```

As-is:

`DebugMode & DebugModeFPS`

= `DebugModeButton | DebugModeData & DebugModeFPS`

(which is parsed as `DebugModeButton | (DebugModeData & DebugModeFPS)`)

= `DebugModeButton | (4 & 2)`

= `DebugModeButton | 0`

= `DebugModeButton`

= `1`

With parentheses as I suggest:

= `(DebugModeButton | DebugModeData) & DebugModeFPS`

= `5 & DebugModeFPS`

= `5 & 2`

= `0`

Comment: nice nice. #define DebugMode (DebugModeButton|DebugModeData) or #define DebugMode DebugModeButton+DebugModeData also works well. Give it a high priority. Thank you very much.

Comment: Better yet, don't use macros, use constants, and avoid this any many other macro pitfalls.

Comment: @zszen I recommend against using + operator because if you have some bit flags already set you will end up unsetting it and setting some other flag unintentionally.

Comment: @Richard . Thx, I now usally use bit operator instead + operator